# I need to turn over my new Galaxy Note 7 for recall and cannot find a way to remove or log off my gmail accounts

Tags: gmail

I have the new Note 7. I have a few g-mail accounts, and have linked them all with my Note 7. Now, I've learned that I need to turn over my phone for the massive Note 7 recall, but have yet find a way to log out my g-mails without deleting these account, which I want to keep. I have changed my passwords to each account, gone into each account and scrolled down to details to remove the accounts from all other web activities, but the phone has not yet been "hardware swapped" back to my old Sprint phone, and I can still see all of my g-mail account and each email within each account. I can click on any email to do whatever I desire, and I can also still send emails - all without ever having to log in with the new password. All I want to do is remove the g-mails from that (my Note 7) so I can hand it over for the recall. I am simply confused as to the g-mails that will remain on the phone. Can anyone offer up some advise to this old gal, who hasn't yet begun to understand how this works? Thank you!

Comment: I found a youtube video that explained it all so have it all under control now and no longer need assistance with this issue after-all. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Please go to Settings>Accounts>Google. You can find all your Gmail accounts here.

If you want to remove it, tap on the email>Menu(Three dots on top right or more)>Then remove account.

Comment: YOU NEED TO PRESS ON THE ACCOUNT A FEW TIMES BEFORE YOU GET THE REMOVE OPTION IN MENU

Comment: Thank you anyway, I really appreciate your help! I had stated in a comment to my own question, that I'd found a youtube video on this so was able to remove my gmails entirely. The Note 7 is just a little different than my other Note so removal wasn't as intuitive, yet, as on my  older Note, because there was more to it than that, but the removal was completed and the Note 7 has been returned for recall. Thanks!!